# Get match result by name is not possible when using Java 10

Tags: kotlin

Heading says it all:

```
Java version information, tested on opensuse:
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Retrieving groups by name is not supported on this platform.
at kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations.getMatchResultNamedGroup(JDK8PlatformImplementations.kt:28)
at kotlin.text.MatcherMatchResult$groups$1.get(Regex.kt:260)
at kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt.get(RegexExtensions.kt:33)
```

Question: Will this be fixed?
I am pretty sure that I can get the first regex, but that might not be possible in many other cases.

Thanks for your help (sorry for formatting, posting from mobile website)

Comment: It might get fixed, you can track the issue status here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20865

Comment: Despited the "fixed" status on KT-20865, this still isn't working for me on Java 11. I filed [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29241) to track the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the issue [KT-20865](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20865), this problem is fixed in Kotlin 1.3.20

Answer (score 1):

It is reproduced in Android (Java 8). Use

```
REGULAR_EXPRESSION.toRegex().find(sample)?.groupValues?.getOrNull(1)
```

instead, where needed groups start from 1 (see also https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/group-values.html).